# Divide TimeSpan in c#

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a TimeSlot class:

```
public class TimeSlot
{
private TimeSpan start;
private TimeSpan end;
}
```

I need to implement this function:

```
Public List<TimeSlot> GetDividedTimeSlot(TimeSlot timeslot, int durationInMinutes)
```

The function gets a time slot and time-duration in minutes, and divides the time slot into the maximum amount of time slots that are in the range of its start and end time and each one of them has the same time-duration as given. The time slots should also be in differences of quarter of an hour from each other.

For example:

Assume the timespan is 17:00 – 19:00, and the duration is 90 minutes.

The expected list is:
17:00 – 18:30 , 17:15 – 18:45, 17:30 – 19:00

What I tried:

```
              List<TimeSlot> dividedTimeSlots=new List<TimeSlot>();
              TimeSpan start = timeSlot.start;
              TimeSpan end = timeSlot.end;
              TimeSpan currentEnd = new TimeSpan();
              TimeSlot newTimeSlot;

              while (end.Subtract(start).TotalMinutes >= durationInMinutes)
                {
                    //currentEnd should be equals to the start time + timeDuration
                    currentEnd = ((DateTime.Now + start).AddMinutes(durationInMinutes)).TimeOfDay;
                    newTimeSlot = new TimeSlot();
                    newTimeSlot.start = start;
                    newTimeSlot.end = currentEnd;
                    dividedTimeSlots.Add(newTimeSlot);
                    start = (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15) + start).TimeOfDay;
                }
            return dividedTimeSlots;
```

But the given result is strange, it is not connected to the original time.

What is wrong is the code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The use of `DateTime.Now` (twice) seems strange, it should be removed. The output should have nothing to do with the current date and/or time, but that is what `DateTime.Now` gives you.

Comment: Yeah, I also wondered about it, but I saw it in some question here as a correct way to add minutes to TimeSpan. In which another way can I add minutes to TimeSpan?

Comment: TimeSpans can be added together.  Create a TimeSpan that represents the amount you want to add and use the `+` operator.  [TimeSpan Addition Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.op_addition?view=net-6.0#system-timespan-op-addition(system-timespan-system-timespan))

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Can you please write it as an answer so I mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of DateTime.Now is the cause of the issue.  Since DateTime.Now refers to this instant in time, the resulting time is now based on the current time combined with the spans you are working with.

You have 2 options for adding time.  Both are essentially the same, each returning a new TimeSpan object.

**Using `+` Operator**

> Adds two specified TimeSpan instances.
>
> > Languages that do not support custom operators can call the Add method instead.
> > The equivalent method for this operator is TimeSpan.Add(TimeSpan)

```
var originalTime = new TimeSpan(1, 10, 30);
var additionalTime = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 30);

var resultingTimespan = originalTime + additionalTime;
```

**Using `Add` Function**

> Returns a new TimeSpan object whose value is the sum of the specified TimeSpan object and this instance.

```
var originalTime = new TimeSpan(1, 10, 30);
var additionalTime = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 30);

var resultingTimespan = originalTime.Add(additionalTime);
```